# ++./stack.sh:main:1351 devstack ./stack.sh fails

Tags: openstack, devstack

I ran `./stack.sh` to install `devstack` on a controller node (virtual machine ubuntu 14.04 lts) for a multi-node lab setting. The script failed, and the log for the same is as follows:

```
2017-02-16 09:50:14.632 | +[3242m./stack.sh:main:1349                     (B[m [[ -x /home/stack/devstack/local.sh ]]

2017-02-16 09:50:14.647 | +[3242m./stack.sh:main:1350                     (B[m echo 'Running user script /home/stack/devstack/local.sh'

2017-02-16 09:50:14.647 | Running user script /home/stack/devstack/local.sh

2017-02-16 09:50:14.661 | +[3242m./stack.sh:main:1351                     (B[m /home/stack/devstack/local.sh

2017-02-16 09:50:14.666 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.667 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.667 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.668 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.669 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.672 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.672 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.673 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:14.674 | /home/stack/devstack/local.sh: line 11: /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-manage: No such file or directory

2017-02-16 09:50:15.057 | WARNING: setting legacy OS_TENANT_NAME to support cli tools.

2017-02-16 09:50:15.067 | WARNING: setting legacy OS_TENANT_NAME to support cli tools.

2017-02-16 09:50:28.646 | +----------------------------+----------+
2017-02-16 09:50:28.646 | | Field                      | Value    |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.646 | +----------------------------+----------+
2017-02-16 09:50:28.646 | | OS-FLV-DISABLED:disabled   | False    |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.646 | | OS-FLV-EXT-DATA:ephemeral  | 0        |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | disk                       | 0        |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | id                         | 6        |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | name                       | m1.micro |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | os-flavor-access:is_public | True     |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | properties                 |          |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | ram                        | 128      |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | rxtx_factor                | 1.0      |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | swap                       |          |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | | vcpus                      | 1        |
2017-02-16 09:50:28.647 | +----------------------------+----------+

2017-02-16 09:50:34.052 | More than one SecurityGroup exists with the name 'default'.

2017-02-16 09:50:36.188 | More than one SecurityGroup exists with the name 'default'.

2017-02-16 09:50:36.285 | ++[3242m./stack.sh:main:1351                     (B[m err_trap

2017-02-16 09:50:36.328 | ++[3242m./stack.sh:err_trap:517                  (B[m local r=1

2017-02-16 09:50:36.405 | stack.sh failed: full log in /opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log.2017-02-16-150336

2017-02-16 09:50:36.408 | Error on exit
```

The multiple security groups with the name default exist but on running nova secgroup-list i get the following:

```
stack@user-VirtualBox:~/devstack$ nova secgroup-list

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/novaclient/client.py:278: UserWarning: The 'tenant_id' argument is deprecated in Ocata and its use may result in errors in future releases. As 'project_id' is provided, the 'tenant_id' argument will be ignored.
warnings.warn(msg)
WARNING: Command secgroup-list is deprecated and will be removed after Nova 15.0.0 is released. Use python-neutronclient or openstackclient instead.
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| Id                                   | Name    | Description            |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
| de21f869-215e-46c0-9e36-28da003c2d7a | default | Default security group |
+--------------------------------------+---------+------------------------+
```

I need to install `devstack` in controller setting on this vm and this error is making `./stack.sh` to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. The error occurs when ./stack.sh invokes local.sh to create the rules for the default security group. As the default security group exists for each tenant, hence this error occurred. 
The solution was to comment out the part in local.sh that dealt with the creation of these rules, and then to create them later explicitly by mentioning the id of the security groups rather than the name to avoid any clashes.